# Share internet from Nokia S60 (Symbian) to Android 4.4

Tags: reverse-tether

The devices are Nokia N95 and Sony Xperia Z1.

I tried [JoikuSpot](http://www.joiku.com/products) to share the connection over Wi-Fi, but Android doesn't support ad hoc access points.

I was about to give [BlueVPN+](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.blue_vpn) a try, but its author states that it `doesn't work with Kit Kat versions (4.4.*) due to a VPN issue`.

Is there any other solution?

Comment: If the developer of the app says it can't be used with KitKat, it can't be used with kitkat.